# Angular not loading after Wiselinks page load in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, wiselinks

The issue I'm having is that when loading pages via Wiselinks that have Angular set to display on them, I am seeing the actual Angular variables instead of the correct values (e.g. {{ song.name }} instead of the song's name).

However, when I refresh the page, Angular displays correctly.

It looks like the issue is that the document is already ready after the site initially loads.

Then when you click a Wiselinks link, Wiselinks just loads the content within a specified div, which means that the events fired at document ready won't be fired again, and angular will not bootstrap.

I have seen a couple solutions, but I am not having luck with any.

One of which would be to use the page:always functionality within Wiselinks, and to manually bootstrap angular when the page is loaded via Wiselinks.

However, when adding the code below to the controller corresponding to the page set to load, I am not able to see the following code execute:

```
var page_init;

$(document).ready(function() {
  return page_init();
});

$(document).off('page:always').on('page:always', function(event, xhr, settings) {
  return page_init();
});

page_init = function() {
 angular.bootstrap(document);
};
```

Even when I replace 'angular.bootstrap(document);' with 'alert("test!");' the code still does not fire.

Should I be putting this code in the view's corresponding angular controller?

Also, is this the correct method to bootstrap angular after a page loads via Wiselinks.

I have read the documentation, and have seen similar StackOverflow questions, but I am not very familiar with jQuery, so it kind of reads as greek to me.

My code is below:

AtmoDashboardCtrl.js:

```
(function (){
  function AtmoDashboardCtrl($resource, ModalService, $interval, Restangular, ShareMusic, angularSoundManager) {

    //CV: atmo_dashboard.html.erb

    var page_init;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      return page_init();
    });
    $(document).off('page:always').on('page:always', function(event, xhr, settings) {
      return page_init();
    });
    page_init = function() {
      return alert("test!");
    };

    var currentUserDiv = document.getElementById('div-atmodashboarduser-data');
    var currentUserId = currentUserDiv.getAttribute("data-atmodashboarduser-id");

    ShareMusic.sayHello();

    var vm = this;


    // SAVING SONG TO PLAYLIST

    vm.setSong = function(songId){
      ShareMusic.setSong(songId);
    };

    // SAVE SONG TO LIBRARY - LIBRARY ID, SONG ID

    vm.saveSongToLibrary = function(selectedSongId) {
      ShareMusic.saveSongToLibrary(selectedSongId);
    };

    // SHARE SONG - CREATE POST, CREATE POST_SONG
    vm.sharePostSong = function(songId) {
      ShareMusic.sharePostSong(songId);
    };

  }
  angular
      .module('AtmoDashboardCtrl', ['angularModalService', 'ShareMusic', 'angularSoundManager'])
      .controller('AtmoDashboardCtrl', ['$resource', 'ModalService', '$interval', 'Restangular', 'ShareMusic', AtmoDashboardCtrl]);
})();
```

atmo_dashboard.html.erb:

```
<div ng-controller="AtmoDashboardCtrl as dash">
  <div id="div-atmodashboarduser-data" data-atmodashboarduser-id="<%= current_user.id %>"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column column-4" style="height: 90px; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1); border-radius:5px;">
      <h3>Atmo Schedule</h3>
      <%= render partial: 'atmo_events/atmo_events' %>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-4" style="height: 90px; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1); border-radius:5px;">
      <h3>Atmo Artists</h3>
      <% @atmo_artists.each do |atmo_artist| %>
        <p><%= atmo_artist.user.name %></p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-4" style="height: 90px; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1); border-radius:5px;">
      <h3>Atmo Charts</h3>
      <div>
        <div class="topartist" style="cursor:pointer" ng-repeat="song in searchSongs | orderBy:'-rank'">
          <a music-player="play" add-song="song">{{ song.name }}</a>
          <a style="cursor:pointer;" music-player add-song="song"><img src="/assets/plus_2.png"/></a>
          <a style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click="dash.setSong(song.id);"><img src="/assets/add_list.png"/></a>
          <button ng-click="dash.saveSongToLibrary(song.id);">LIB +</button>
          <button ng-click="dash.sharePostSong(song.id);">Share Song</button>
          <strong>{{ song.rank }}</strong>
          <a rel="nofollow" data-method="post" ng-href="/songs/{{song.id}}/up-vote"><img src="/assets/vote_arrows/up_arrow.png" alt="Up arrow"></a>
          <a rel="nofollow" data-method="post" ng-href="/songs/{{song.id}}/down-vote"><img src="/assets/vote_arrows/down_arrow.png" alt="Down arrow"></a>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
    <div class="column column-8" style="height: 90px; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1); border-radius:5px;"><%= link_to "Store", products_path, data: { push: true } %>/Radio/<%= link_to "Contests", contests_path, data: { push: true } %>/Blogs&News</div>
    <div class="column column-4" style="height: 90px; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1); border-radius:5px;">
      <h3>Channel/Youtube</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

UPDATE:

So I have found that changing my code to the following in my atmo_dashboard.html.erb file (and removing ng-app="atmosphere" from my index.html.erb file) is successfully manually bootstrapping my angular app when the view loads.

```
<div id="dash">
  <div ng-controller="AtmoDashboardCtrl as dash">
    <div id="div-atmodashboarduser-data" data-atmodashboarduser-id="<%= current_user.id %>"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-4" style="height: 90px; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1); border-radius:5px;">
        <h3>Atmo Schedule</h3>
        <%= render partial: 'atmo_events/atmo_events' %>
      </div>
      <div class="column column-4" style="height: 90px; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1); border-radius:5px;">
        <h3>Atmo Artists</h3>
        <% @atmo_artists.each do |atmo_artist| %>
          <p><%= atmo_artist.user.name %></p>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="column column-4" style="height: 90px; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1); border-radius:5px;">
        <h3>Atmo Charts</h3>
        <div>
          <div class="topartist" style="cursor:pointer" ng-repeat="song in searchSongs | orderBy:'-rank'">
            <a music-player="play" add-song="song">{{ song.name }}</a>
            <a style="cursor:pointer;" music-player add-song="song"><img src="/assets/plus_2.png"/></a>
            <a style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click="dash.setSong(song.id);"><img src="/assets/add_list.png"/></a>
            <button ng-click="dash.saveSongToLibrary(song.id);">LIB +</button>
            <button ng-click="dash.sharePostSong(song.id);">Share Song</button>
            <strong>{{ song.rank }}</strong>
            <a rel="nofollow" data-method="post" ng-href="/songs/{{song.id}}/up-vote"><img src="/assets/vote_arrows/up_arrow.png" alt="Up arrow"></a>
            <a rel="nofollow" data-method="post" ng-href="/songs/{{song.id}}/down-vote"><img src="/assets/vote_arrows/down_arrow.png" alt="Down arrow"></a>
            <br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
      <div class="column column-8" style="height: 90px; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1); border-radius:5px;"><%= link_to "Store", products_path, data: { push: true } %>/Radio/<%= link_to "Contests", contests_path, data: { push: true } %>/Blogs&News</div>
      <div class="column column-4" style="height: 90px; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1); border-radius:5px;">
        <h3>Channel/Youtube</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  console.log("Hello from Dashboard Load INIT");
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('dash'), ['atmosphere']);
</script>
```

The problem now is that my app can only be bootstrapped one time, and I now have access to angular in my view, but not in my index file.

Because of this, it looks like I would need to initialize the controller manually after the Wiselinks page load.

Is this possible? If not, is there a way to bootstrap the same app twice? After some research, it doesn't look like bootstrapping twice is possible, so I'm thinking that initializing the controller would be the best bet.

Any ideas? Or perhaps a better solution?

Thanks in advance!